# Rails Rake task: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC

Tags: ruby

I have this code in my rake task:

```
variables[:hotels].push(
{
  :id => offering.ID,
  :name => offering.vendor.Name,
  :placing_name => offering.Name,
  My::Media::Account.find_by_guid(offering.VendorID).photos.each do |p|
    :hotel_images.push({
      :id => p.id,
      :image => p.image,
      :url => "http://m.website.com/uploads/photo/image/#{p.id}/#{p.image}"
    })
  end #there is an error
})
```

When I'm trying to run it, I'm getting an error `syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC` in Terminal. It points on last `end`. Where did I make a mistake? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't insert executable code there. Ruby expects to see the next key in the hash you're defining, not a blob of code. You also can't `push` onto a symbol that way, `:hotel_images.push({` isn't ever going to work.

If you want `:hotel_images` to map to an array, you need to move the key outside the loop, and use `map` instead of `each`:

```
variables[:hotels].push(
{
  :id => offering.ID,
  :name => offering.vendor.Name,
  :placing_name => offering.Name,
  :hotel_images => My::Media::Account.find_by_guid(offering.VendorID).photos.map do |p|
    {
      :id => p.id,
      :image => p.image,
      :url => "http://m.website.com/uploads/photo/image/#{p.id}/#{p.image}"
    }
  end
})
```

While this is not syntactically "correct", it's going to cause you grief performance-wise. Since this appears to be happening in a loop, you should be using `includes` to include the `photos` association, and you should only be selecting the attributes you're interested in.